# <ol> tag doesn't increment from 1 and stays at 1 while using in a 'for' loop in HTML

Tags: html, jekyll

Firstly, I don't know anything about HTML. I am trying to build a website using [Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_(software)) and found a template for the website, to which I am making modifications.

I have the following code:

```
{% for publi in site.data.publist %}

{% assign even_odd = number_printed | modulo: 2 %}

{% if even_odd == 0 %}
<div class="row">
{% endif %}

<div>
  <ol>
  <li>{{ publi.title }}</li>
    <!--   <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/pubpic/{{ publi.image }}" class="img-responsive" width="33%" style="float: left" />
 -->  <p>{{ publi.description }}</p>
  <p><em>{{ publi.authors }}</em></p>
  <p><strong><a href="{{ publi.link.url }}">{{ publi.link.display }}</a></strong></p>
  <!-- <p class="text-danger"><strong> {{ publi.news1 }}</strong></p>
  <p> {{ publi.news2 }}</p> -->
  </ol>
</div>

{% assign number_printed = number_printed | plus: 1 %}

{% if even_odd == 1 %}
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

There is a YAML file in the `site.data.publist` which has a number of members, each with different fields. The *for* loop helps to go through all the members of the YAML file.

As you can see in the code, I am using the `<ol>` tag in the *for* loop and I have used the `<li>` tag for the `publi.title` (a field in the members of the YAML file). But all I get is one repeating for all the members in the YAML file. [I have attached the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS2Ud.jpg).

Comment: Right now you're generating invalid HTML and the browser somewhat tries to fix it. If you look in the dev tools you'll see, that there is not one list with multiple entries, but multiple lists with one entry each.To fix it, you'd need, e.g., to move the closing `</li>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [sirko mentioned in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794078/ol-tag-doesnt-increment-from-1-and-stays-at-1-while-using-in-a-for-loop-in-ht/66794207#comment118071282_66794078), you are generating invalid HTML.
First of all, the `<ol>` may only contain `li` as direct children. So make sure to put everything else also within the `li` tag.

But your real problem is that you generate the `ol` tags *within* your loop. As mentioned in the comment, your output the contains *multiple* lists with one element each, not *one list* with n elements.

In order to change that, you have to move the `ol` outside of the *for* loop. (And then make sure you still generate valid HTML => see point 1.)

Comment: You guys are legends. Thank you very much